# How to create an object instantiation with exposing methods, while not using classes?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

I have a task to solve, with certain limitations. This is the task:

Create an object Shape for instantiating a new Shape that will output to the console a text based on how many segments the shape is composed by.
The Shape object has one property "type" that stores this value and can be accessed via it's showType() function.

By default property type value is 3.

Shape has few methods:

### Describe()

behavior:

- If the number of types are strictly less than 3 , null or undefined Shape.describe() should set them to 3 and at the same time "console.log" the message:
  "A Shape needs to have at least 3 segments, it will be set to 3" and at the same time set segments property value to 3.
- If the number of the types are equal to 3 , Shape.describe() should "console.log" the message:
  "The Shape you created is a triangle composed by 3 segments" and at the same time set the type property value to 3.
- If the number of the types are equal to 4 , Shape.describe() should "console.log" the message:
  "The Shape you created is a quadrilateral composed by 4 segments" and at the same time set the segment property value to 4.
- If the number of the segments are equal to 5 , Shape.describe() should "console.log" the message:
  "The Shape you created is a pentagon composed by 5 segments" and at the same time set the segment property value to 5.
- If the number of the segments are equal to 3 , Shape.describe() should "console.log" the message:
  "The Shape you created is a hexagon composed by 6 segments" and at the same time set the segment property value to 6.
- If the number of the types are bigger  than  6 , Shape.describe() should "console.log" the message:
  "The Shape you created is a generic shape composed by {number_bigger_than_six} segments" and at the same time set the segment property value to {number_bigger_than_six}.

### Increase()

behavior:

- Shape.increase() should increment object property type value, and at the same time log the appropriate message using Shape.describe()

example:

const square = getShape(4) //--> sets the type property to 4
Shape.describe() //-->  console.log('The Shape you created is a quadrilateral composed by 4 segments' )
Shape.increase() //--> console.log('The Shape you created is a pentagon composed by 5 segments' ) and at the same time increment type property of square object.

### whatIs()

behavior:

Shape.whatIs()  //--> Open a new browser window that links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon

#### The default code that needs to be used for this task is :

```
const getShape = function (countOfTypes) {
  // Create a Shape Object

  const result = {
    showType() {
      // Return (Number) the current count of types
      return Number (segments);
    },
    describe() {
      // log 'The shape you created is a *** composed by * 
segments'

    },
    increase() {
      // Increase the type property of a created shape by 1 and 
log the appropriate sentence in describe()      
    },
    whatIs() {
      // Open a new window that links to 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon

    }
  };
  return result;
};

//Test and use Cases

const square = getShape(4);
square.describe(); // The shape you created is a quadrilateral 
composed by 4 segments
square.increase() // The shape you created is a pentagon composed 
by 5 segments

const generic = getShape(18);
generic.describe(); // The shape you created is a generic shape 
composed by 18 segments

generic.whatIs(); // Open a new window that links to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon


const emptyShape = getShape(); // Emit a log message: 'A shape 
needs to have at least 3 segments, it will be set to 3' and set it 
to 3
```

This absolutely need to be solved by using existing code, which restrict us from using classes, I was used to  solve these kind of things using classes, so i tried to lean towards more for me confusing topic Factory functions.

I am trying to find a working solution here, but I am not expert on this matter, and kinda lost.

#### I am trying to do something like this.

```
const getShape = function (countOfTypes) {
  // Create a Shape Object
  return {
    type: result.showType()
  }

  const result = {
    showType() {
      // Return (Number) the current count of types

      return Number (countOfTypes);
    },
    describe(countOfTypes) {
      // log 'The shape you created is a *** composed by * segments'
      if (!countOfTypes || countOfTypes < 3) {  
        console.log ('A shape need to have at least 3 segments. It 
will be set to 3.')
        result.showType(3);
      }
      if (countOfTypes > 6){
        console.log("The shape you created is a generic shape 
composed by " + countOfTypes + " types")
      }

      if (countOfTypes == 3 || countOfTypes == 4 || countOfTypes == 
5 || countOfTypes == 6) {
        console.log ('The Shape you created is ' + segmentName + ' 
created from ' + this.type + ' segments.')
      }

      let names = ['triangle', 'quadrilateral', 'pentagon', ' 
hexagon']
      segmentName = names[countOfTypes - 3];

    },
    increase() {
      // Increase the type property of a created shape and log the 
same sentence in describe()
      Number(countOfTypes) + 1;
      console.log ('The Shape you created is ' + segmentName + ' 
created from ' + this.type + ' segments.')       
    },
    whatIs() {
      // Open a new window that links to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon
      window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon');
    }
  };
  return result;
};

//Test and use cases

const square = getShape(4);
square.describe(); // The shape you created is a quadrilateral 
composed by 4 segments
square.increase() // The Shape you created is a pentagon composed 
by 5 segments

const generic = getShape(18);
generic.describe(); // The Shape you created is a generic Shape 
composed by 18 segments

generic.whatIs(); // Open a new window that links to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon

const emptyShape = getShape(); // Emit a log message: 'A Shape needs 
to have at least 3 segments, it will be set to 3' and set it to 3
```

To be honest I am little bit stuck, and getting that result is not defined error, any help with solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"... I was used to solve these kind of things using classes..."* you know how to use classes then show your code using classes instead of this pseudo-code.

Comment: @zer00ne unfortunately, requirements of the task are to not use the classes, than to use rather factory functions, and adapt code to the predefined path. That is why I am asking the help in the first place, I don't "excell" in these kind of situation. I was hoping that someone who is much better than me in these things would offer some constructive advice, or teach me how to adapt to situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
const result = {
    showType:  function() {
```

So you can do `getShape().showType()`.
Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Is not the:

    showType: function () same as showType() ?

Comment: `showType: function() {` means object `result` has property named `showType`, which is a function. If you say `showType()`, you didnt really say what is the object property

Answer (score 0):

## [Object Composition](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6#3914)

Object composition is creating objects from object and primitive data types (Booleans, Strings, Numbers, etc.) You want to avoid using classes but want shared methods between objects then you're correct -- a factory function would be a viable solution. The term is called concatenative inheritance -- [composing objects by extending an existing object with new properties](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-hidden-treasures-of-object-composition-60cd89480381#1bc9):

> ```
> Object.assign(properties, method(properties), ...)
> ```

I cannot write within the confines of your homework assignment, hopefully this will steer you in the right direction. The following demo will receive a number 3 - 20 from the user, it will create an object and from that object's properties generate HTML with the name of a polygon, as well as the link and image of said polygon. I leave the description to you.

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/mJncFILf1ZygJ7BWWOEX/)

### Demo

**Details are commented in the demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    form {
      font: 400 16px/1.25 Consolas
    }
    
    input,
    output,
    button {
      display: inline-block;
      font: inherit
    }
    
    input {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 250px;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='poly' onsubmit='return false'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Regular Polygons</legend>
      <label> Sides: </label>
      <input id='qty' type='number' min='3' max='20'>
      <button id='btn'>GO</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='view'></fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    /* Composite Objects */
    /*
    getType has the name() method which will convert props.sides into the 
    proper index of the types array to get the correct value for prop.type
    */
    const getType = (props, types) => ({
      name: () => {
        props.type = types[props.sides - 3];
      }
    });

    /*
    getLinx has the link() and image() methods props.type is used by the former 
    and props.sides and the dir array are used by the later to interpolate 
    strings into template literals that become urls for props.url and props.img.
    */
    const getLinx = (props, dir) => ({
      link: () => {
        props.url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${props.type}`;
      },
      image: () => {
        switch (props.sides) {
          case 4:
            props.img = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Six_Quadrilaterals.svg`;
            break;
          default:
            props.img = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/${dir[props.sides - 3]}/Regular_polygon_${props.sides}_annotated.svg`;
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    /*
    polygon() function factory passes 2 parameters sides (Number) and tag 
    (String) props is the object that will have the three methods name(), link(), 
    and image() by concatenative inheritance using Object.assign().
    */
    const polygon = (sides, tag) => {
      const types = ["Triangle", "Quadrilateral", "Pentagon", "Hexagon", "Septagon", "Octogon", "Nonagon", "Decagon", "Undecagon", "Dodecagon", "Tridecagon", "Tetradecagon", "Pentadecagon", "Hexadecagon", "Heptadecagon", "Octadecagon", "Enneadecagon", "Icosagon"];
      const dir = ["e/eb", "3/3d", "0/01", "3/38", "7/75", "e/e5", "b/ba", "b/b9", "f/f8", "0/06", "a/a6", "e/e1", "d/d0", "e/e4", "c/c6", "d/d8", "1/18", "2/23"];
      let props = {
        tag: tag,
        sides: sides,
        type: '',
        url: '',
        img: '',
        desc: ''
      };
      return Object.assign(props, getType(props, types), getLinx(props, dir));
    };

    /* DOM Interface */
    /* 
    HTMLFormControlsCollection is a terse API that references tags by id or name
    */
    const poly = document.forms.poly;
    const qty = poly.qty;
    const view = poly.view;

    /*
    #btn is regustered to the click event. When triggered, the value of #qty 
    (.valueAsNumber) and the number of #view's chid elements (.childElementCount)
    become arguments for the function displayPoly().
    */
    poly.btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const vert = qty.valueAsNumber;
      const count = view.childElementCount;
      displayPoly(vert, count);
    });

    /* 
    displayPoly() passes the number from #qty and interpolates the number #view
    with a generic word to create a unique string to pass it to polygon() as the
    2nd argument. Next, the object creayed by polygon is returned and referenced
    as shape. shape's methods are invoked and then the new values are generated.
    The values of type, url, and img are interpolated into a string which is then
    rendered as HTML and prepended to #view.
    */
    const displayPoly = (number, index) => {
      let name = `shape${index}`;
      let shape = polygon(number, name);
      shape.name();
      shape.link();
      shape.image();
      let Type = shape.type;
      let Url = shape.url;
      let Img = shape.img;
      let item = `
  <figure id='${name}'>
    <figcaption title='${shape.sides} Sides'>${Type}</figcaption>
    <a href='${Url}'>
      <img src='${Img}'>
    </a>
  </figure>
  `;
      view.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', item);
      return false;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort @zer00ne you certainly gived me a food for thought, your solution looks very interesting, but unfortunately is not the complete answer to my task. Aside from that, it is very good, and I appreciate the time you provided to steer me in that direction, it certainly could prove useful.

Comment: It actually exceeds your homework assignment but different enough so you'd have to understand it and actually work a solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the homework requirements, it tests your understanding of [JavaScript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Here is how closures can be used for the solution:

Firstly, the base code given already returns a result object. The result object returning exposes methods which are invokable from outside: `showType()`, `describe()`, `increase()`, `whatIs()`. What you write inside these functions have access to scope of `getShape()` function.

I created a variable called `segments` and a function named `getName()` inside `getShape()` function. As you see these can only be accessible inside `getShape()` function.

Here is the full code below:

```js
const getShape = function (countOfTypes = 3) {
  // Create a Shape Object
  let segments = countOfTypes;

  function getName() {
    if (segments < 3) {
      return null;
    } else if (segments === 3) {
      return "triangle";
    } else if (segments === 4) {
      return "quadrilateral";
    } // vice versa
  }

  const result = {
    showType() {
      // Return (Number) the current count of types
      return Number (segments);
    },
    describe() {
      // log 'The shape you created is a *** composed by * segments
      if (getName() === null) {
        console.log("A shape needs to have at least 3 segments, it will be set to 3, and set the type property value to 3");
      } else {
        console.log(`The shape you created is a ${getName()} composed by ${segments} segments`);
      }
    },
    increase() {
      // Increase the type property of a created shape by 1 and log the appropriate sentence in describe()
      segments++;
      result.describe();
    },
    whatIs() {
      // Open a new window that links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon
      window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon");
    }
  };
  return result;
};

//Test and use Cases

const square = getShape(3);
square.describe();
square.increase();
```

Comment: this looks, almost close to the right point, @Yigit Usta thank you man, i added and hanled remaining cases all of them except empty one. How would you handle case like:
    const emptyShape = getShape() // log A shape needs to have at least 3 
    segments, it will be set to 3, and set the type property value to 3

Comment: @ Yigit Usta also I need to add all of the segments value as a object property in the all instantiated objects. That is missing too, but probably you are right about closures, I think this is the closest way to go.

Comment: If you do not pass any parameters, the segments are defaulted to 3. If you pass a value less than 3 that is an invalid shape. These are both mentioned in the requirements and implemented in the code in my answer. I don't think the teacher wants you to pass segments value to the returned object since showType() shows it. However, if you still want to add it as an object parameter you can write it as segments: segments inside returned result object.

Comment: I see that, but if I try to make const emptyShape = getShape() it should set the default value to 3 and to log the message "Shape have to have 3 segments bla, bla, and set the property value to three. Instead of that engine ignores that line completely and do not log to console anything. Also I did not understand quite this line: "_if you still want to add it as an object parameter you can write it as segments: segments inside returned result object._" Yes I have to add the segments value as a property type to all instantiated objects by request of the task.

Comment: I tried to do it in the getShape function like:

   ` this.segments = segments` but without sucess.